# How can I highlight admin comments?

Tags: comments

Basically what I want is to have all comments posted by admins with different background color than the rest, so they're easily distinguishable.

I wasn't able to find any plugin that would do this though, and hacking it into the theme doesn't look very clean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do the admin comments have a unique css class? if yes, then all you need is some adaptation to style.css; if you don't know, please post a link to your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default WordPress already adds user/admin/post author specific CSS to comments with the following three elements.

`#byuser`
`#comment-author-admin`
`.bypostauthor`

So you can just add something like `#comment-author-admin {background-color;blue;}` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your Theme:

1. Uses the default comment-list markup, via `wp_list_comments()`, or
2. Manually applies the `<?php comment_class(); ?>` template tag appropriately

...then all you need to do in order to style *author* comments is to target the CSS class `.bypostauthor`.

So, if, in your case, "author" = "admin", then you're all set.

However, if your site has multiple authors, and/or multiple admins, then that won't be sufficient.

Fortunately, the `comment_class()` template tag can accept an argument, used to pass additional classes (it is also passed through the `comment_class` filter, but that is more difficult to use in this case).

So, try something like this:

```
$additional_comment_classes = '';

if ( user_can( $comment->user_id, 'administrator' ) ) {
    $additional_comment_classes = ' byadmin';
}
```

Then, when you call `<?php comment_class(); ?>`, call it as `<?php comment_class( $additional_comment_classes ); ?>`

Note: you'll need to be using a callback to `<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>` in order to modify `comment_class()` in this manner. If you don't want to go that route, then you'll need to add the class via the `comment_class` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Open your style.css on your template folder and add this:

```
.authorstyle { background-color: #B3FFCC !important; }
```

Now open your comments.php and find code that should look something like this:

```
<li <?php echo $oddcomment; ?>id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>"></li>
```

and replace it with this code:

```
<li class="<?php if ($comment->user_id == /*Give Author ID here*/) $oddcomment = "authorstyle"; echo $oddcomment; ?>"></li>
```